# Why doesn't my div inside a span work properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing the following `HTML` markup:

```
<span> Some Text
    <div id="ch">татата</div>
</span>
```

and styles:

```
span{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: aqua;
}
#ch{
    width:100px;
    height:100px
    background: yellow;   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4VT/)

1. Why is the `height` property not applied to a `div` element which inside the `span`, but width is applied?
2. Why is the right border of my `span` is missing?

Answer (score 32):

Your markup is incorrect ( *plus missing semi-colon as quoted by Steini, mentioning this for sake of completeness of answer* )

**Answer 1** : `span` is an `inline` element, so having a `div` inside `span` is a bad idea, also, it would be better, if you nest `span` inside `span` and give inner span `display:block` property!

**Answer 2** : add `display:block` to `span` to change the default behavior

[**working fiddle with correct markup**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4VT/4/)

[**fiddle with the layout you wanted**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4VT/5/)

Comment: Don't know why folks are downvotiing, but one possible way to improve the answer is to provide reference for information that "div inside span is a bad idea".  I found support for that statement in wikipedia:  "A span element may not contain block-level children", [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div], although their reference is a bit difficult to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are missing a `semicolon` after `height: 100px` <- this `;` is missing in you css file

Answer (score 2):

span `display:inline` you must set it `display:inline-block`
but this not standard you must use div span always use for text 
[your fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4VT/2/)

Answer (score 2):

First answer: You forgot the semi-colon after height style, that's why it is not rendered.

Second answer: If you look closely, the border appears after the div. This is because you 
are inserting block level element inside inline element. So, block level element takes it to the next line and then it takes the whole line. On the very next line you can see the right border for the span.

It is bad practice to put block level element inside inline element. In fact, I do not see any practical use of this kind of structure. Please, correct it if you are learning.

Answer (score 2):

By default div's is a block element and span is an inline element. Block elements always flow vertically and inline elements always flow next to each other from top left to the bottom right depends on screen width.
We can use inline elements under the block element, not vice versa. If we override we expect to see some issues like this on responsive layout.

Answer (score 1):

span is an inline element so it will not take notice of your height and width.  For this you need to give it either:

`display:block;` or `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

span is an inline-element, while div ist not. you should consider swapping them..